# Boost converter drive inductor into saturation

Tags: boost, converter, saturation

The boost converter I'm trying to put together might seem a little bit odd, as it's made out of parts that belong in a museum, but I've quite a lot of them so I thought to use them for something. I couldn't find a model for the SR306 diode I'm actually using, so in the simulation I've used a random Schottky diode.

[image: Boost schematic]

Its purpose is to boost 5V coming from a USB brick, into 12V to light up some LEDs. The inductor isn't anything commercially available, rather I made it myself by winding a fairly thick wire around a core I had floating around. I measured it to be 80 uH which should be plenty given the converter's 62.5 kHz switching frequency (generated using an Arduino UNO). Running some simulations confirmed that the converter was running in CCM and the inductor's ripple was well below 1A.

While the simulation results were promising, the actual circuit behavior is strange: on startup it correctly boosts the input voltage however *after about 1 second*, the voltage drops so much that the Arduino just resets; something's draining a lot of current as the transistor gets real hot, real fast. I managed to save the waveform that it produces in this small time frame: the yellow trace is coming from the BD441's collector, whereas the purple one is the inductor's voltage. Strange thing is that I seems to be "normal" for the first second, then it goes haywire.

[image]

I've quadrupled check every single connection and component and the only thing left me to blame is the inductor. I made another one with a different core, this time measuring 440 uH and still, I couldn't get the converter to work properly. I did some research and it seems that inductor saturation isn't that uncommon, however this leaves me quite puzzled as there isn't nearly enough current going around this circuit (both peak and average).

What could it be that's going terribly wrong?

Edit: I've added a picture of the inductor I wound up. The wire is a 1 mm², solid core, copper wire. This one has is the 80 uH inductor and has a shiny core, the other one (440 uH) has a more "raw" core, quite rough on the surface. I actually know nothing about these two, to be honest.

[image]

Comment: How many turns and what cross sectional area on the core? Increase the frequency and unwind some turns?

Comment: What makes you say there isn't enough current for saturation? Do you know what the saturation characteristics of your core are?

Comment: You can see the transistor starting to come out of saturation ... increasing base drive a little may help, and ... what heatsink did you put on it? it may simply be overheating.

Comment: Randomly winding wire around a core can get you in trouble.  Core saturation is likely. You need to show a picture of your inductor. The DC current flowing through the inductor is probably the culprit. BTW, wire diameter matters. AC resistance goes up as wire diameter increases due to proximity effect, DC resistance goes down as wire diameter increases. There is an optimal diameter to use, but probably not overly important for your design. Magnetics design is fairly complicated, especially without an impedance analyzer.

Comment: 62.5 kHz is already the maximum the ATMega328p can push. My belief for not reaching saturation current is pure gut feeling, I actually don't know much about inductor design beside the basic physics so this might be a really obvious question to answer.

Comment: Depending on the core and the number of turns, it can take very little current to saturate an inductor! In DC-DC converters, you want to generally use a powder core, with a distributed air gap to drive up the saturation current. What your cores are... Couldn't say. Do they have any writing on them? They could be anything, and I wouldn't use them for this (or anything) without knowing the details.

Comment: I would check to see if the transistor is going into thermal runaway. Not saying it is, but something to be concerned about.

Comment: Better, but please measure the outer diameter, the inner diameter and the height of the core please.

Comment: @Hearth Unfortunately no. I've these things floating around since forever an I don't even know anymore where I got them. The only discernible difference I could feel between the two (beside the exterior roughness) is the fairly unstable inductance value for the 440 uH, as it jumped around by just moving it. The 80 uH is more stable.

Comment: @winny Physical dimensions are: outer 2 cm, inner around 1.2 cm with a 1.2 cm height. The 440 uH core has similar dimensions: 2 cm outer, 1.1 cm inner, 1.5 height.

Comment: Thanks. That leaves you with 8mm x 12 mm = 96 mm^2 area. Assuming 1 A peak current, you have LI=NAB with 80u x 1 A = 11 x 96(m)^2 x B. Solve for B and you have 75 mT. You say 1 A ripple, but what's your peak current? If 1 A, then 75 mT is not enough to saturate the core and your problem lies elsewhere. If 5 A peak and ferrite core, you are probably saturating it.

Comment: @winny You were right, the problem was somewhere else, namely the transistor. I'll answer my own question for completeness

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inductor was indeed saturating however this was an effect not the cause. The true problem was located inside the relic of past that is the BD441. It took awhile to figure out that the simulation didn't tell the whole story, namely that C2 is too small for the comically slow delay of the BD441. Basically it was always conducting, hence the saturating inductor.

I increased C2 from 50 nF to 200 nF and it managed to do the trick. When the control signal goes from high to low (yellow trace), the transistor takes his time to switch off (green trace). Given the quite ridiculous 50% efficiency measured, I'd say that this transistor isn't quite up to the task.

[image]